# How to have a binary number with constant lenght

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write a test_bench for a dynamic size register.
I defined a parameter variable like this and instantiated a register module:

```
  parameter integer regSize = 8;

  register #(.size(regSize)) R1 (
   .clock(clk),
   .reset(rst),
   .enable(enb),
   .regIn(in),
   .regOut(outp)
  );
```

now forexample I want to define "in" variable ( the 4th input of module )

```
  reg [regSize - 1: 0] in = (regSize)'b0;
```

I expect this works as : `reg [regSize - 1: 0] in = 8'b0;`
But it doesn't.

I get this error:

```
near "'b": syntax error, unexpected BASE, expecting ';' or ','
```

How should I write this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concatenation repeat structure:

```
reg [regSize - 1: 0] in = {regSize{1'b0}};
```

Or in System Verilog you can do :

```
reg [regSize - 1: 0] in = '0;
```

You might also need something similar for adding e.g. 1 to a counter with variable length:

```
...
counter <= counter + {{(regSize-1){1'b0}},1'b1}; // regSize>1!
```

As that becomes difficult to read I prefer to use a localparam :

```
localparam [regSize-1:0] value_1 = {{(regSize-1){1'b0}},1'b1}; // regSize>1!
   ...
   counter <= counter + value_1;
```

Note that it can get rather messy if you also want to have a width of 1 bit as but I assume adding 1 to a 1 bit counter is likely to be a design error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pad 0's to a number in Verilog, it does that automatically for you. You can just do

```
reg [regSize - 1: 0] in = 0;
```

Comment: I was wondering how to assign values like 8'b11010110 to register "in"

Comment: `in = 8'b11010110;` It gets truncated or padded with 0's to fit the size of `in`. If you want that pattern replicated, then do `in = {$ceil(regSize/8.0){8'b11010110}};`